# Solving an Equation with Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, equation

I was studying regular expressions to augment my knowledge of the subject. During my research I found a math problem which was about solving the equation 3x+2y=14. I am baffled at my discovery since I did not know this was possible. This finding taught me that there are a lot of things I need to learn. I think this idea of how to solve an equation like this has a lot of potential. This is the exercise I found:

```
const r = /.../
const fourteen = '1'.repeat(14)
const [_0, threes, _2, twos] = fourteen.match(r)
console.log(threes.length/3, twos.length/2)
```

I am a little bit confused by their answer. Which regex should be the one going in the first line of the program. Also, why is the match of the regex with a string with the number 1 repeated 14 times? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not getting this. What is your question?

Comment: `'1'`.repeat(14)` gives you a string `11111111111111`, i.e `1` repeated argument times

Comment: Adding a link to the original might be helpful here, we can't make heads or tails out of it the way you've posted it.

Comment: yeah sorry, the only thing missing is the equation we want to solve, it is 3x+2y=14, there is nothing more to the exercise. we have to fill the first expression with the correct regex but for now this seems really hard with the knowledge i have thats why i wanted some help.

Comment: @FrankDrebbin Please post the whole problem next time. :P See the edits to my answer. If you just want a hint, look at how the match() function works in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I think the expression should be `/.../g` in order to get the four matches.</s> I'm not sure about what potential this could have, but it's a nice little exercise. It basically

- creates a string of 1s of length 14
- <s>globally</s> applies an expression <s>consuming `111` each time it matches</s> and saves the individual matched strings in four named variables
- <s>plays a little with the match length, variable names and division, suggesting `3/3 = 1` and `3/2 = 1.5`</s>

No equation solving happening as such. :)

**Edit**

Ok, halt everything. The above was under the assumption that the OP's original post was complete. If the problem actually is to solve the equation `3x + 2y = 14` by writing a regex, then one possible solution is... SPOILER

> `/(.{6})()(.{8})/` which creates the output `2 4`, with `3*2 + 2*4 = 14`

**Explanation**

The point - as I understand it - is to come up with an expression which, when matched against `11111111111111`, induces the `match()` function to return four values, two of which are needed for solving the given equation.

Now let's first look at which whole numbers (an assumption) satisfy `3x + 2y = 14`. For me, `x = 4, y = 1` springs to mind, `x = 2, y = 4` would also work. Let's remember the latter for now.

So, what does that mean in terms of matching the given string? Well, since `x` is procured by `threes.length/3` and y is the result of `twos.length/2` - this corresponds to the given equation's `3x` and `2y` - it stands to reason that the `match()` return values representing `x` and `y` must be exactly 3x and 2x as long as the numeric values satisfying the equation respectively.

Sticking with `x = 2, y = 4`, that means we are looking for a `match()` result where the second value has length 6 (3 * 2) and the fourth value has length 8 (2 * 4). Now we need to know how `match()` works and write an expression to cater to it.

> When an expression has capturing groups, `match()` returns an array containing the matched string and all captured strings in order. So, in the exercise: `_0` is the whole match, `threes` is the content of the first capturing group, `_2` that of the second, `twos` that of the third. That means we need three capturing groups and in order to match 6 and 8 characters (out of 14 total) for the 2nd and 4th position (ironically), the group in-between must be empty. That results in the aforementioned expression.

Comment: sorry about the incomplete question. Anyway, how is that solving the equation? could you explain what is that doing? thanks a lot!

Comment: @FrankDrebbin I edited my answer.